# Can't send tag name for provider in Java to Pact Broker

Tags: java, spring, junit, pact, pact-broker

As you see below ,I have passed to JVM system properties values of "pact.provider.tag", "pact.provider.version", "pact.verifier.publishResults".The results is publishing to the Pact Broker ,but tag name of provider is not publishing.Please advice me how to publish tag for the provider

@MockBean
    private FactoringService service;

```
@BeforeEach
public void setupTestTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", 9012, "/adapter-factoring"));

    System.setProperty("pact.provider.tag", "dev");
    System.setProperty("pact.provider.version", "1.0.1");
    System.setProperty("pact.verifier.publishResults", "true");
}

@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
public void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {

    context.verifyInteraction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding the value in your POM.XML?

FYI,
https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/pact-jvm-provider-maven#publishing-pact-files-to-a-pact-broker

Comment: I have already solved this issue, there was a bug in Pact with Junit.This is the link from that I created on there GitHub page : https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/960

Comment: **  great! ** Got it